# Как безопасно получить rw права на docker.sock из контейнера?

Tags: php, linux, docker, docker-compose

Я использую **docker-php** с nginx + php-fpm (проект docker-compose). Когда я пытаюсь запустить пример из [документации](http://docker-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/container-run/):

```
<?php
use Docker\API\Model\ContainersCreatePostBody;
use Docker\Docker;
$docker= Docker::create();
$containerConfig = new ContainersCreatePostBody();
$containerConfig->setImage('nginx:latest');
$containerConfig->setCmd(['echo', 'I am running a command']);
$containerCreateResult = $docker->containerCreate($containerConfig);
var_dump($containerCreateResult);
exit;
```

то получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Http \ Client \ Socket \ Exception \ ConnectionException - Permission denied
```

Насколько я понял, то проблема заключается в группе пользователя, от которого работает php-fpm, эта группа не имеет rw прав на смонтированный файл сокета docker.sock (в проекте docker-compose видно, что я монтирую его из хоста в контейнер)

### Конфигуарция:

**docker-compose:**

Директория shell содержит приложение на yii2, в котором я и использую docker-php.

```
version: '2'
services:
web:
  image: 'nginx:latest'
  container_name: web
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
  volumes:
    - './:/shell'
  networks:
    - backend
    - frontend
  restart: always
php:
  build: ./docker/php/
  container_name: php
  volumes:
    - './:/shell'
    - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
  environment: []
  networks:
    - backend
  restart: always
networks:
frontend:
  driver: bridge
backend:
  driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile для php-fpm: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/dmitr1y/23634d143cad728d8eccb451651792ff) (файл слишком большой ~100 строк, поэтому вынес)

В этом контейнере docker установлен для эксперемента, для работы docker-php он абсолютно не нужен.

**Версии ПО:**

- Docker version 1.13.1
- docker-compose version 1.8.0
- Kubuntu 17.10 x64

В интернете находил схожие проблемы ([раз](https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php/issues/222), [два](https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php/issues/239), [три](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135897/access-docker-socket-within-container) ...), их решением было добавление пользователя, от которого работает приложение, в группу www-data. 
Если php-fpm работает от имени www-data, то непонятно почему не было доступа, когда я добавил пользователя www-data в группу docker (на хосте).

Если я назначу права 777 на docker.sock, то все будет работать, но это не лудшее решение =)

Comment: а зачем вам запуск контейнера внутри контейнера? для озвученной задачи (запустить три изолированных процесса) это совершенно излишне.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin реализую задачу по управлению контейнерами на php. Необходимо с помощью docker-php создать новый контейнер, который запустился бы на хосте (а не внутри контейнера). Исходя из наличия различных сервисом (например, portainer) это вполне возможно (запускать сервис по управлению контейнерами в контейнере)